# Is there a way to check the syntax of a crontab file without actually installing it?

Tags: linux, cron

I know that "crontab -e" performs a syntax check before attempting to install an edited crontab.  However, I am looking for a way to verify that the syntax of a crontab file is correct, even if:

- the crontab is for a different user that may not even exist on the system where I am doing the editing
- I do not want to install the crontab on the system where I'm doing the editing

An analogy for what I'm looking for is the way you can run "xmllint somefile.xml" to verify that a file is valid xml.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chkcrontab/

Comment: or python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chkcrontab/1.6

Comment: **or** https://github.com/lyda/chkcrontab

Answer (score 0):

One way if you have total control of the server is to create a new user (or use a test user), and edit the crontab there.

An alternative is to change the command portion of the crontab entry to something like "echo 1 > /tmp/blah" and see if that works correctly, though obviously this depends on when the entry should fire and what the consequences of it not firing are.

The trouble is that no options can really guarantee that something will run correctly in cron unless the environment you test in is configured the same way.  Remember that cron's environment is generally significantly different from a "normal" user's.

Ultimately, the "right" process is that if this a production environment, all changes should be scripted and all release scripts tested in a release test environment.  That way you have repeatability and testing.